How can CMake access an external header file?
I already read many questions similar to this, but they could not fix my problem.
The internal CMakeList.txt cannot find the source file (header?) located one level above: external_header.h
Project structure:
- cmake_test_external_headers/
    - CMakeLists.txt
    - external_header.h
    - cmake_test_external_headers/
        - CMakeLists.txt
        - internal_header.h
        - cmake_test_external_headers.cpp

Top level CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.28)    
project ("cmake_test_external_headers")    
add_subdirectory ("cmake_test_external_headers")
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

external_header.h:
#pragma once
static const int testExt = 456;

Bottom level CMakeLists.txt:
include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")

string(TOUPPER ${PROJECT_NAME} PROJECT_NAME_UC)

set(${PROJECT_NAME_UC}_PUBLIC_HEADERS "external_header.h")
set(${PROJECT_NAME_UC}_HEADERS "internal_header.h")
set(${PROJECT_NAME_UC}_SOURCES "cmake_test_external_headers.cpp")

message("CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}")
message("PROJECT_NAME = ${PROJECT_NAME}")
message("PROJECT_NAME_UC = ${PROJECT_NAME_UC}")
message("${PROJECT_NAME_UC}_PUBLIC_HEADERS: ${${PROJECT_NAME_UC}_PUBLIC_HEADERS}")
message("${PROJECT_NAME_UC}_HEADERS: ${${PROJECT_NAME_UC}_HEADERS}")
message("${PROJECT_NAME_UC}_SOURCES: ${${PROJECT_NAME_UC}_SOURCES}")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} 
    ${${PROJECT_NAME_UC}_PUBLIC_HEADERS} 
    ${${PROJECT_NAME_UC}_HEADERS} 
    ${${PROJECT_NAME_UC}_SOURCES}
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)

internal_header.h:
#pragma once
static const int testInt = 123;

cmake_test_external_headers.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include "internal_header.h"
#include "external_header.h"
//#include "../external_header.h"
//#include "whole/path/to/external_header.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Test int: " << testInt << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Test ext: " << testExt << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

CMake output (relevant part):
1> [CMake] CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = C:/Users/z0052d3h/source/repos/cmake_test_external_headers
1> [CMake] PROJECT_NAME = cmake_test_external_headers
1> [CMake] PROJECT_NAME_UC = CMAKE_TEST_EXTERNAL_HEADERS
1> [CMake] CMAKE_TEST_EXTERNAL_HEADERS_PUBLIC_HEADERS: external_header.h
1> [CMake] CMAKE_TEST_EXTERNAL_HEADERS_HEADERS: internal_header.h
1> [CMake] CMAKE_TEST_EXTERNAL_HEADERS_SOURCES: cmake_test_external_headers.cpp
1> [CMake] -- Configuring done (3.2s)
1> [CMake] CMake Error at cmake_test_external_headers/CMakeLists.txt:20 (add_executable):
1> [CMake]   Cannot find source file:
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     external_header.h
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] CMake Error at cmake_test_external_headers/CMakeLists.txt:20 (add_executable):
1> [CMake]   No SOURCES given to target: cmake_test_external_headers
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake] CMake Generate step failed.  Build files cannot be regenerated correctly.


CMake does not look in the include path list, that is only passed on to the compiler when building. The "external header file" need to have the actual (relative or full) path.

On a different note, "external header files" are typically part of a third-part library or project, and should usually not be listed as a source file for the targets you build.

Or... Do you mean that the "external header file" is one that should be distributed by your application or library? Then just treat it as any other "internal" header file, and just set up your installation to copy or use that "external" header file, not the internal ones.

@Someprogrammerdude: I already tried to specify the full and relative header paths (see commented lines), but I still get the same error.

I mean you need to specify the actual path to CMake.

@Someprogrammerdude - Yes, specifying the relative path (../external_header.h) in CMakeLists.txt works. If you write it as an answer I will accept it.

I usually declare some variables like ${MY_SHARED_INLCUDE_DIRS} in the root cmake files and reuse those (so that if you move directories around you only have to update scripts in one place) and then you can use that in your  target_include_directories

@PepijnKramer - I noticed that simply specifying the ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} base directory works as well.
